# How to get name of dataframe column in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pandas, this can be done by `column.name`.

But how to do the same when it's a column of Spark dataframe?

E.g. the calling program has a Spark dataframe: `spark_df`

```
>>> spark_df.columns
['admit', 'gre', 'gpa', 'rank']
```

This program calls my function: `my_function(spark_df['rank'])`
In `my_function`, I need the name of the column, i.e. `'rank'`.

If it was pandas dataframe, we could use this:

```
>>> pandas_df['rank'].name
'rank'
```

Answer (score 120):

You can get the names from the schema by doing

```
spark_df.schema.names
```

Printing the schema can be useful to visualize it as well

```
spark_df.printSchema()
```

Comment: What I wanted to know is the name of the column which is the input parameter to my function.
The calling program will call my_function by my_function(spark_df['rank'])

Inside my_function how would I know the name of the column that is passed?

Comment: You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.col` to access a column by name. E.g., `df.filter( col(var_name) > 1)`

Comment: @ShuaiYuan,
That's not what I want.

Inside my_function(col) how would I know the col name?

Calling function calls by my_function(spark_df['rank'])
Inside my_function, I want to extract 'rank' as the column name from the input parameter: col

Comment: That seems like an odd request. But you could change your function to take a string for the name of the column

Comment: You can change your functions to `myfunc(df, name)` then you have access to `name` in your function. When you need to use that column in the dataframe, do `df[name]`

Comment: Or, you could make use of [`Dataframe.Column.__repr__`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/column.py#L430)

Comment: In my case in did a check for the name of the column `if 'col_name' in df.schema.names: # do something`. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 28):

The only way is to go an underlying level to the JVM.

```
df.col._jc.toString().encode('utf8')
```

This is also how it is converted to a `str` in the pyspark code itself.

From pyspark/sql/column.py:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Column<%s>' % self._jc.toString().encode('utf8')
```

Comment: This won't pull out the alias if there is one, unfortunately.

Comment: True. but you can easily parse that out if there's an alias. `re.search('AS `(\S*)`', col.alias('some_alias')._jc.toString()).group(1)` -> `'some_alias'`. Of course this isn't perfect, since we're doing some regex parsing, but I would hope it's unlikely you have some column name called "AS `bad`" in it.

Comment: @numeral does the underlying JVM code expose any kind of parser logic that can be used instead of hand-rolling it?

Comment: @shadowtalker It doesn't seem like it after checking https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html

Comment: The alias can also be extracted without using any regex: 

str(column).split(' AS ')[1].split('`')[1]

Answer (score 11):

Depending on the specific case:

1. **Unaliased columns:** `column._jc.toString()` already works fine  (thanks @numeral).
2. **Aliased columns:** (i.e. `column.alias("whatever")` ) the alias can be extracted:

   - **Python**

     ```py
     str(column).split(" AS ")[1].split("`")[1]
     ```
   - **Scala**

     ```
     str(column).split(" AS ")(1).split("`")(1)
     ```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the column names of your dataframe, you can use the `pyspark.sql` class. I'm not sure if the SDK supports explicitly indexing a DF by column name. I received this traceback:

`>>> df.columns['High']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

However, calling the columns method on your dataframe, which you have done, will return a list of column names:

`df.columns` will return `['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']`

If you want the column datatypes, you can call the `dtypes` method:

`df.dtypes` will return `[('Date', 'timestamp'), ('Open', 'double'), ('High', 'double'), ('Low', 'double'), ('Close', 'double'), ('Volume', 'int'), ('Adj Close', 'double')]`

If you want a particular column, you'll need to access it by index:

`df.columns[2]` will return `'High'`

Comment: Going along the idea: `[x[0] for x in df.dtypes]`

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer is very very simple...

```java
// It is in Java, but it should be same in PySpark
Column col = ds.col("colName"); //the column object
String theNameOftheCol = col.toString();
```

The variable `theNameOftheCol` is `"colName"`

Comment: in python it'd be col._jc.toString()

Comment: When the column is aliased, this returns `col_name AS alias`, while the expected result may be just `alias`.

Answer (score 4):

This should cover even the strangest cases:

- column with/ without an alias
- several aliases
- aliases containing multiple words
- column names surrounded with backticks
- intentional backticks in aliases

```py
def get_col_name(col):
    if str(col)[-3] != '`':
        return str(col).split("'")[-2].split(" AS ")[-1]
    return str(col).replace('``', '`').split(" AS `")[-1].split("`'")[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

#table name as an example if you have multiple

```
loc = '/mnt/tablename' or 'whatever_location/table_name' #incase of external table or any folder 

table_name = ['customer','department']

for i in table_name:
  print(i) # printing the existing table name

  df = spark.read.format('parquet').load(f"{loc}{i.lower()}/") # creating dataframe from the table name
  for col in df.dtypes:
    print(col[0]) # column_name as per availability

    print(col[1]) # datatype information of the respective column
```

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers have been marked as *the* Answer -
I may be over-simplifying the OPs ask but:

```
my_list = spark_df.schema.fields
for field in my_list:
    print(field.name)
```