# pyspark-sql: print alias of an expression

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark I have the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
cc = F.lit(1).alias("A")

print(cc)
print(cc._jc.toString())
```

I get :

```
Column<b'1 AS `A`'>
1 AS `A`
```

Is there any way for me to just print "A" from cc ? it seems I'm unable to extract the alias easily.

Also I think that in spark-sql in scala, if I print "cc" it would just print "A" instead

Comment: This post will guide you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746752/how-to-get-name-of-dataframe-column-in-pyspark. However,based on the docs and this answer it seems like there is no way to do this without parsing the "AS" etc.

Answer (score 0):

This goes deep into the `Column` Scala data model which is not mapped to Python:

`cc._jc.named().name()`

This is the `name` argument of the [Alias](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1b9fd67904671ea08526bfb7a97d694815d47665/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/namedExpressions.scala#L145) instance.